# Yet another Facebook OAuth error 500

Tags: facebook, oauth

Today I moved my facebook application to [nodejitsu](https://www.nodejitsu.com/) and I couldn't figure out what was wrong in the `oauth/dialog` GET request.

I validated that I had:

- added the new application domains to my application settings
- the redirect URI was good, for example, `app.nodejitsu.com`

I played around so much with these properties and I didn't figure out why it was still giving me a 500 error. I checked most of the posts on stackoverflow and although they all seemed to be valid errors, they didn't seem to reflect my issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I found my problem.

After migrating the app to nodejitsu my `localhost` app still worked. So I decided to remove `localhost` from the accepted app domains in the facebook settings. When I tested it again I got this error:

*"Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains."*

Ok, so this made my think. If the problem was with an incorrect domain I would still get this message for nodejitsu, so I had an error with the request I reckoned.

I manually edited the request and I figured out that my `redirect_uri` **did not start with http.**

I changed this and it worked.